# ghc-mtl fails to build with ghc-7.8

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-api

I'm trying to build ghc-mtl-1.2.1.0 with ghc-7.8.3 and I'm getting these error messages:

```
Control/Monad/Ghc.hs:42:15:
    No instance for (GHC.MonadIO Ghc)
      arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
    Possible fix:
      use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
        so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (GHC.ExceptionMonad Ghc)

Control/Monad/Ghc.hs:46:15:
    No instance for (MonadIO GHC.Ghc)
      arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
    Possible fix:
      use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
        so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (MonadIO Ghc)

Control/Monad/Ghc.hs:49:15:
    No instance for (GHC.MonadIO Ghc)
      arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
    Possible fix:
      use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
        so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (GHC.GhcMonad Ghc)
```

Same errors with ghc-7.8.2.

I have tried to figure out which of the over 9000 types and/or modules called `Ghc` and/or `GHC` and/or `MonadIO`  is responsible for this, but so far no luck.

So my questions are:

- What change is responsible for this breakage?
- Is it possible to fix it without a downgrade from 7.8.3?

Comment: I can build `ghc-mtl-1.2.1.0` just fine with `ghc-7.8.2`... could be some weird preprocessor-mixup you're experiencing, but I've no idea why.

Comment: @leftaroundabout This doesn't seem to be the preprocessor. Can you paste your ghc-pkg --list somewhere?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/leftaroundabout/bafead50d9e5fb0612d0

Comment: @leftaroundabout thanks, I'll check it out when I get home to my computer.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have looked at the diffs, no obvious clues. [Here](http://lpaste.net/107791) is my list. [Here](http://lpaste.net/107792) is my verbose build log. Can you post your verbose build?

Comment: @leftaroundabout there was the problem in the package list after all, see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The problem was the transformers-0.4.1.0 package, which was installed alongside transformers-0.3.0.0 that comes with ghc. The transformers package provides `Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO` class. It was pulled into build twice, once from transformers-0.4.1.0 and once from transformers-0.3.0.0, which resulted in a conflict.

I have seen the duplicate package but didn't realize it was the source of the problem. My mistake was that I have hidden transformers-0.4.1.0 with `ghc-pkg hide`, tried to build ghc-mtl, the problem persisted, and I decided that transformers was not the reason. Hiding is of course not enough, I should have removed it instead.

Uninstalling transformers-0.4.1.0 and downgrading its dependencies solved the problem.